# How to start Hangfire each 30 and 00 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, cron, jobs, hangfire

How can i start Hangfire every 00 and 30 minutes?

For Examle, i start project 13:20, Hangfire must start 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00 ... etc.

I know how to start hangfire every 30 minutes expression ("*/30 * * * *") but my hangfire need to start not only every 30 minutes but also at exact xx:30 and xx:00 times.

What should be my cron job expression?

https://crontab.cronhub.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0,30 * * * *
```

This is not a coding-related question though.

Answer (score 0):

you Should use this

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("Recurring"), "*/30 * * * *");
```

Reference to my question in Hangfire forums: http://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-create-cron-job-that-is-executing-every-15-minutes/533